# Symfony Form with CollectionType and EntityType child form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, entity, symfony-forms

i have a problem with a Symfony form.
The error is:

> ***Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given***

The entities in question are Immovables and Appointment and this is the code of relation:

Immovables:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Appointment", mappedBy="immovables", cascade={"persist"})
 */
public $appointment;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->appointment = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

Appointment:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Immovables", inversedBy="appointment", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="appointment_immovable")
 */
public $immovables;

 public function __construct() {
    $this->immovables = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

I have a form when there is a CollectionType like this:

```
->add('immovables', CollectionType::class, array(
    'entry_type' => ImmovableAppointmentType::class,
    'allow_add' => true,
))
```

In form child ImmovableAppointmentType, i have an EntityType like this:

```
->add('editoriale', EntityType::class, array(
     'class' => 'AppBundle:Immovables',
     'label' => false,
     'mapped' => false,
     'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control'),
     'multiple' => false,
     'empty_data'  => null,
     'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('i')
                  ->where('i.deletedBy IS NULL');
        },
 ))
```

I extend in Twig template like this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/847Kf/4/ used in Symfony's documentation.

In controller the error is in the persist but i don't receive error form in fact it's valid.
But i receive an error like this:

> **Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given**

How can I do for solved this error??

Comment: Please paste your controller code.

Comment: you've already asked the same question yesterday.

Comment: Have you found the solution?